# Should "I am new to" be removed as noise?

Tags: discussion, edits

alot of the time i see questions either at the start or the question say

> I am [very] new to [INSERT LANGUAGE]

or at the end go

> apologies if this question is noobish but i am new to [INSERT LANGUAGE]

I know we aught to remove salutations, signatures, "thanks" and "URGENT i need this..." from questions/answers because they are noise and aren't relevant to the question however for the above i'm not sure if the such content is relevant or not as i see it in 2 ways

**It's noise** because we don't care how skilled you are at a language when asking a question. you just need to put effort into asking your question and  showing your research and/or debugging. and if i was being cynical it almost sounds like *"please give me a free pass because i'm new and don't know better"*

or

**it's not noise** because it hows the poster's experience and understanding. for instances a new programmer to PHP probably wont know the difference between server side and client side code or how Namespaces work (though it doesn't excuse them from google their question)

so should "I am new to" comments be removed as noise?

Comment: ............yes

Comment: If they are just noise, then yes. But if they in some way helping the question, the no.

Comment: I just saw this twice tonight. Interesting.

Comment: Of course not! I am new to is a keyword for people to search for noob question when SO doesn't have a question difficulty level ranking.

Comment: The person is (hopefully) not new to asking questions.  Most try to use it as an excuse to ask a bad question.  Its not an acceptable excuse.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent: I wonder how many people actually try to use that. It would be a horribly noisy signal, as I'd expect most *good* questions - even if they're ones from those who are new to a language/platform/programming - not to include them.